# Which numbers are constructible in $n$-th root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I was wondering how we find exactly which numbers are constructible numbers in a field $ℚ(a)$ where $ a = ζ \sqrt{2}$ and ζ is an nth root of unity.

For example the primitive $3$-rd root of unity...

If I know that the degree of the extension $[ℚ(ζ, \sqrt{2}): ℚ] = 4$ can I conclude that the constructible elements would be those numbers of $ℚ(a)$ which have a degree which is a power of 2? Is it enough to just conclude that or can we find the actual numbers?

Also I was wondering if this extends for all constructible $ a = ζ \sqrt[b]{2}$ i.e. $ a = ζ \sqrt[3]{2}$?

Any comments or discussions would be great thank you.

Comment: If $\mathbb Q(\zeta,\sqrt 2)/\mathbb Q$ is Galois with a power of 2 as its degree, then all its elements are constructible, including those of $\mathbb Q(a)$.

Comment: Oh right! If you don't mind me asking, would this apply to all $\ =ζ\sqrt[b]{2}$ for example if I have $=ζ\sqrt[4]{2}$ where extension $[ℚ(ζ, \sqrt[4]{2}):ℚ]=8$ which is a power of 2?

Comment: Also what is the reason for this? I do not have anything in my notes explaining so that's why I am curious. I haven't actually reached the point in my notes which defined "Galois" so that's why  I am wondering if it can be explained at my stage

Comment: When constructing numbers, each construction step corresponds to solving a quadratic equation. So by constructing a number, we are adjoining a root of a quadratic polynomial, and the degree of the this extension is 2. Doing this a finite number of times, we get an extension whose degree is a power of 2, and everything in this extension is constructible. Galois theory tells us that if an extension is in a way well-behaved (Galois), then the reverse is also true: **continued**

Comment: it's sufficient for the degree to be a power of two to find such a series of extensions of degree 2, making elements of such an extension constructible. So to apply to your other example $\mathbb Q(\zeta,\sqrt[4]{2})$, the extension needs to be Galois (it has to be the splitting field of a family of polynomials). That's the case if $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$ contains a primitive fourth root of unity, otherwise $\mathrm i\sqrt[4]2$ is not contained, so the polynomial $X^4-2$ splits only partially.

Comment: That's a great explanation thank you very much for your time and help.